# What's the performance impact of global and instance methods in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was discussing a possible solution with a workmate and, we agree that expose a global function would be the easiest and fast way, but we disagree about the approach to do that. He argues that add many instance methods could cause performance loss and recommend to add a global function instead. I think that does not have a difference because, in both approaches, global or instance, the method would be exposed and consequently load into memory. However, I've not a deep understanding of how Vue works and, I hope someone to explain in more detail the performance impacts in both ways.

With global function I mean, directly into vue like that
`Vue.myGlobalMethod = function () {}`

And instace like that:
`Vue.prototype.$myMethod = function (methodOptions) {}`

Comment: do you mean with global function to populate the window object?

Comment: No, with global function I mean, directly into vue like that 
'Vue.myGlobalMethod = function () {}'

And instace like that:
`Vue.prototype.$myMethod = function (methodOptions) {}`

Comment: You probably need a mixin. You can check out more about mixins [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). With regard to performance, I don't expect using a mixin to have performance problems. If anything, it will make your bundle size smaller (you will write fewer lines of code) and your app will be more maintainable. Single Page Applications(SPAs) generally load all the javascript in the initial load - one of the disadvantages unless you are using optimisation techniques such as code-splitting, lazy loading etc.I don't know if this

Comment: That's a good point Tony I'll consider your advice the next time, but I'm still interested in knowing about the performance impact of these two approaches.